# Eclipse undo changes to project to particular time?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to undo changes to a project till a particular time? Like say, restore project to how it was at `1:00pm`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the editor in your eclipse, do this, **Right Click -> Replace With -> Local History...**

From the list of entries in **Revision Time**, select the revision you want, compare the changes, and if they look okay, replace it.

Done!

Comment: Just to note, if memory serves, local history is removed if Eclipse is restarted.  So if OP closed Eclipse since 1:00pm, I believe he won't be able to use local history.  Although +1 as your answer is the only one I can think of :)

Comment: @david99world Thankfully eclipse is running since yesterday! :D BTW, what is 'OP'?

Comment: @user2256798, original poster

Comment: @david99world - I thought that was the case too. But strangely, I can see the local history of my file since morning, despite having restarted, not just the eclipse, but my machine too. Several times that is! Quite amusing to me!

Comment: Yeah that seems really mad as my eclipse hasn't kept my local history since I restarted my machine (I don't know about Eclipse), I'm curious to know where it persisted the local history when you restarted :p

Comment: @david99world: That's wrong. Look at the preferences for local history. It is limited by default to 7 days, 50 entries, or 1 MB size, whatever comes first.

Comment: Please elaborate how this answers OP. When I try it, I only get the history of the file (not the project), and if I don't have files open, the editor doesn't have a right-click menu.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the project folder, choose "Restore from Local History..."
Check the files that you would like to get reverted back. 
This won't undo the fetch per se, but it'll get your files back.