# How do I revert the changes that I made and saved on eclipse (for the same .java file)?

Tags: eclipse, revert

I made some changes to my code in Eclipse in a way that it would work for one input file. When I tested my code with other input files, the other input files were not working, so I want to revert the changes. I tried this by pressing command+z, but it would not let me revert the changes that I already saved. Is there a way to revert those changes and get the previous version?

Thank you.

Edit: One advice was to right click on the editor, but I am getting the same options as the other post advised. [Here is my result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoFoM.png)

Comment: Use 'Replace with > Local History' see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16058185/2670892)

Comment: I am able to find any other files under local history. Is there any other way? My eclipse has been running from last night though, I slept my laptop but it was still opened.

Comment: 'Replace With > Local History' **not** 'Restore from Local History'